# Neural network preprocessing

Tags: neural-network

I'm working on school project about data prediction in NN I have my data normalized and I have three input and one output
My questions is

- what is the different between the taring data and test data (is the training data supposed to be the input data and the test the output data)
- what is testing rate is it any random number or is there rule  to find it
- what is training error

and my final question is after training my data I remember something about error I'm not quite sure but do I need to find the error of my prediction and how to find it

I know my questions might not be clear but I'm just confused and tried to explain it as much as I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering in a school spirit: Let's suppose you are given 10 solved exercises to study. You do study them, and then the teacher tests you on these exact exercises. You do well on the test. However, there is an important question. Why did you do well?? Did you really understand the exercises, or did you just memorize them?? And how can the teacher know ??

There is only one way: The teacher must test you on a set of *similar* but *different* exercises. If you also do well on them, you have gotten a feel for the subject, and you are able to *generalize* the knowledge you acquired. If not, you probably memorized them, without understanding a thing. This kind of knowledge is useless.

The same happens with neural networks. You use some patterns to (*training set*) to train them. But, to check if they are able to generalize, you have to test them on a different set of patterns (*test set*) without the network knowing the correct answers. Ideally, you should have small differences in performance between the two sets, that is good generalization ability.

So, both train and tests sets are inputs, not outputs. The only difference is when you use them, the training set during the training, and the test set after it. The training/test set rate is the percentage you got correct of the training/test sets respectively. The training/test error is the complementary, that is, the percentage you got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply might come late but I will just complement the previous answer by saying that in *supervised learning* **both** the training set and the test set are input-output pairs. By structure alone they are exactly the same, a set of input and their corresponding output(or label) pairs. There is no difference in structure between both.

As blue_note said, they are just used in different occasions: one during training and one after that